# How to copy weight paint to another object

Tags: animation, weight-painting

I have a t-shirt model that was attached to one skeleton. I removed the weights and bones of one skeleton, transferred the t-shirt to the second skeleton and transferred the weights from the second skeleton onto it. But a few bones bend the shirt wrong. Is there a way to transfer and replace several "weight paints" from the old skeleton, while maintaining the new skeleton?

Comment: Do you still have the old model with the old weights? If yes, you can use that object and simply swap the armature in it's armature modifier, without removing/recreating any weights (assuming the deforming bones names are the same in both skeletons). For more problematic situations, try the Data Transfer modifier.

Comment: Yes, I have the old model with the old weights, but skeletons are different.

Comment: But are the bones ***named*** differently?

Comment: Do you want to **selectively** combine weights of the new and the old model perhaps?

Comment: Yes, bones named differently, and yes, I need to selectively combine weights.

Comment: Definitely look up the "Data Transfer" Modifier. You can choose which of the groups to transfer.

Comment: Just to be more clear, "weight" is a property that belongs to vertices into a vertex group, not to an armature. Every time you have a mesh with an armature modifier that points to a skeleton and its vertex group has the same name as a bone of that armature, the bone will move that vertex group. So renaming the bones and/or the vertex groups can be a good starting point, without any need of "removing" weights.